# Can you work without an Artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, save

I am having trouble with elements that are on and near the edge of the Artboard being cut off when I go to save the image.

For example: Let's say I create the document with an Artboard size of 800 by 800 and then I create a Rectangle shape that is also 800 by 800 and I Align it perfectly and then I proceed to add elements near the edge plus a Stroke to the Rectangle, rather it's inside or outside, and then I go to save the image as a .png (or whatever) the Stroke and objects near and on the edge get cut off.

And no matter what I do I cannot make the Artboard just a few pixels (or whatever) less or more and I cannot extend the rectangle just a few px's less or more to make up for whatever is happening.

So, I have looked and looked through the (ever elusive), Adobe Illy Manual for an answer but have not been able to come close to an answer/solution. This has now (at this very moment), made me wonder if one can work with Illy without an Artboard so that this problem will ... well, not be a problem.

I have even tried using an Artboard much bigger than I need and then fitting the Artboard to the Selected Artwork but I still end up with the same problem.

Thank you so much for reading my long post. I appreciate your time and efforts to help me navigate this annoying issue. Be well,
Kara

Comment: Hello, I do hope I did the send responses to my email correctly. Because I entered my email and then it said I would no longer receive emails. ??

Answer (score 1):

1) When you "save for web" your PNG, you can uncheck the box "clip to artboard." It should only save the design, not the artboard.

2) One option is to add a rectangle with no border and no color, and make it a bit bigger than your artboard or at the same size. You can put it on a different layer, and lock it so it doesn't get in the way. Or simply lock it on the same layer as your other artwork, in the background.

When you'll export your file, this should become the new "edge" of your image.

If you want your new artboard to fit that invisible rectangle, you can select it and then go in the menu "object", then "artboard" and then select "fit artboard to artwork."